# Помогите с грамматикой

Tags: грамматика, выбор-слов, недопустимая-метка

Вы пришли к какому-то решению? Мы и  Айише ханум сообщили что  кроме законадотельство мы вам еще сможем помочь и c развитием бонусной системы.

Comment: Грамматика правильная, кроме падежа у законодательства. Пунктуация и орфография неверные.

Comment: А по мне, так все там неверное)  Грамматика, стилистика, орфография и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

Ответьте, пожалуйста, к какому решению вы пришли?

Мы (не понятно кто мы ?) и Айша(без и или без й Айша или Аиша) Ханум(с большой же, имя ведь? хотя фраза не очень понятная, вы сообщили Аише ) сообщили, что помимо законодательства(? тут не понятно, законодательства "чего" - *создание законодательства*, *помощь в законодательстве*, "помощь с законодательством" или о что делать?) мы также готовы помочь также развитием "Системы бонусов".

*Мы и Айша Ханум* сообщали, что  помимо (помощи в создании) *законодательства*, мы готовы помочь также с развитием "Системы бонусов".

Курсивом выделил то, что не понятно по значению. Вы сообщали вместе или сообщали ей?

Или "ханум" - это уважительное слово применимое к женщине? тогда:

Ответьте, пожалуйста, к какому решению вы пришли?

Ранее мы сообщали Айше-ханум, что помимо законодательства, мы готовы помочь также с развитием "Системы бонусов".

Comment: Ханум разве имя?

Comment: Или это уважительное к женщине?

Comment: Госпожа; дама в тюркских языках.

Comment: @Серж ясно, писать через дефис надо?

Comment: Со строчной и через дефис. http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=15#pp15